# How can I create PDFs with Play Framework and Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf-generation, playframework

I need to create PDFs with Play Framework and Google App Engine. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific about the Play Framework, but here is a tutorial by Nick Johnson on generating PDFs on App Engine :

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Generating-PDFs-on-App-Engine-Python-and-introducing-Mapvelopes

Comment: But, I need Java solution. I can mixing python and java in GAE?

Answer (score 0):

What are the limitations in GAE? I would assume that you can do it with itext. Furthermore there exist a [play-module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/pdf). I think it depends on your requirements what is the best solution to you. I can imagine that a report-engine wouldn't work very well on GAE, specially BIRT with OSGI-features has [problems](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/596a5fcea4ce9729/865b0c2353ade048?lnk=raot).

Comment: Then I would use iText. It's plain java with no magic and easy to program. But I'm not an expert in this question, perhaps someone know a more elegant way.

Comment: :-( Sorry for the wrong hint. I didn't know that GAE has so much limitations.

Answer (score 0):

iText has dependencies on certain Java classes (java.awt.Color, java.nio.MappedByteBuffer, and so on) which are not allowed by the Google App Engine runtime.

I found a iText hack (2.1.7 version) and works:
[link text](http://cid-2c85f653a571353f.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/shimokita.rb/iText-gae/iText-2.1.7-gae.jar)

Or you can download the patch: [link text](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/download.php?group_id=15255&atid=365255&file_id=331933&aid=2810312)